# SQLEXT function error in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

I was trying to run following SQL in `Aginity` tool in `Netezza` database.

```
select SA1..GET_VALUE_TYPE(POID_DB)
FROM SA1.ACCOUNT_T LIMIT 100
```

I have installed `GET_VALUE_TYPE` functions under Synonyms in `SA1` schema.

But I am getting below error:

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  getDatabaseDetailbyOid: error retrieving database '2376379'

Is there any clue with regards to this error

Thanks

Comment: The GET_VALUE_TYPE functions in the SQLEXT toolkit don't actually include a function called GET_VALUE_TYPE.  They are of the form GET_VALUE_INT, GET_VALUE_DATE, GET_VALUE_VARCHAR, etc. And none of the take a single argument as shown in your example. Are you using a function not provided by the SQL Extension toolkit? Also, please provide the output of " select version(); " and "select regexp_version;"  (the latter being attached to the database and schema that has the SQL EXT toolkit installed.

Comment: @ScottMcg, Thanks for you reply, Following are the output for those queries
`select version() `
`Release 7.0.4.6-P1 [Build 41061] `
`select regexp_version; `
`ERROR [42S22] ERROR:  Attribute 'REGEXP_VERSION' not found `
I get correct output to below though
`substr(sqlext.regexp_extract(col1,'\d\:[0-9]+',1,3),3) `
Further how would we know the number of arguments for those SQLEXT.(functionName)  functions.

Comment: My apologies - I made a typo. It should be "select regexp_version();"  You can find documentation for all of the SQLEXT functions here: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_install_and_setup.html?cp=SSULQD_7.2.0%2F13&lang=en

Comment: @ScottMcG, No worries. Even that I tried before and got following
`ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  Function 'REGEXP_VERSION()' does not exist
 Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
 You may need to add explicit typecasts `

Comment: Looking above at your regexp_extract call, it looks like your SQLEXT functions are installed in the sqlext schema.  Could you try "select sqlext.regexp_version();" ?

Comment: @ScottMcG, All good it gave this output `IBM Netezza SQL Extensions XML / Regular Expression Library Version 1.6.P-2 Build () `. Could you please update above consolidated solution as a `Answer ` and then I can mark it as correct. Really appreciated your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the functions in the SQL Extension Toolkit [at this link](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_install_and_setup.html?cp=SSULQD_7.2.0%2F13&lang=en).

There is no GET_VALUE_TYPE function in the SQL Extension toolkit, although there is a class of functions referred to as "GET_VALUE_TYPE" functions. The individual functions have names such as GET_VALUE_INT and GET_VALUE_VARCHAR, and all require two parameters. They can be found under the "Array Functions" of the documentation linked above.  Based on that, I think you must have a function installed that comes from a different source.  What does your GET_VALUE_TYPE function do?

You can check some basics about the function with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM _V_FUNCTION where FUNCTION = 'GET_VALUE_TYPE';
```

Checking your Netezza version and SQL Extension toolkit version with "select version()" and "select regexp_version()" respectively, show compatible levels. So that looks good.

In Netezza, every object (table, database, user, function, etc.) has an object ID (OBJID).  The error message that you are showing indicates that something is trying to query information about a database whose OBJID is 2376379. If you have the proper permissions, you can run the following query to see if there is an object with that OBJID, and see if it is what you expect it to be.

```
SELECT * FROM _V_OBJECT WHERE OBJID = 2376379;
```

You mentioned a SYNONYM. They can be created only for tables and views, so can you clarify what you meant by where you installed the function?

Hopefully this gets you closer to a solution.